# How do i close ports that i dont need in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, nmap

I have "tested" a little with the nmap command. Now my question is:

Do i have ports that i could close?
Why should i have ports open who run services that i dont need/use?! =)

This ports is open:

- 135/tcp  open  msrpc
- 139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
- 445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
- 5357/tcp open  wsdapi

I have tried to close port 135/tcp. I think i figured out that the port i for remote assistance. I dont want/need that.

I check the windows firewall and there is no activated rule that says port 135 specified should be open.

Im created a rule that should block port 135 on both private,domain,public.

But nmap still says port 135/tcp its open?

Anyone have a soulution on that and what are the other ports have for purpose/use?

And how do i see with nmap if the port is open for private,domain or public?

Comment: Typically you don't close these ports they are usually required for Windows, instead let the firewall block all attempts to use those ports from outside. Also do not run nmap on the system you want to scan.

Comment: Ports on Windows are by default already closed unless a service is running on that port.  Furthermore, with your typically router, traffic can't reach the ports unless you forward traffic to that port in most cases (unless UPnP is enabled). Remote Assistance is by default disabled and has to be specifically opened by the user.

Comment: are you running nmap from another system or the same one? you control `private, domain, or public` by changing the system you are running nmap from, or reconfiguring where it is in relation to the target host, and how windows has been set to characterize that network. I'm guessing that you don't have a windows domain, so the choice between public and private depends on whether you have your network set as Public or Private in the Network & Internet Settings applet.

Comment: Yeah im running nmap on the same system. Is it possible to nmap from outside, say if i borrow neighbours computer?! I have a 192.168.x.x network...

Comment: I'd recommend trying to do it from another station on your LAN. scanning from outside your WAN introduces a lot of complexities. That said, keep in mind that if you have a standard consumer grade router, none of the ports you mention can be reached from outside you LAN, unless you specifically configure your router to forward them. your router will prevent people on other networks from connecting to your devices, while allowing your devices to connect outbound to services on the Internet. if you don;t have any other devices on your LAN, the whole question of open ports becomes moot.